# for loop resulting in undefined behaviour c

Tags: c, pointers, for-loop, undefined-behavior

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
    int i;
    int mult;
    int n;
    int ans;
    ans = mult * i;

    printf("Please enter a multiple you want to explore.");
    scanf("%d", &mult);
    printf("Please enter the number which you would want to multiply this number till.");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for(i = 0; i<n; i++) {
        printf("%d x %d = %d \n", &mult, &i , &ans);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Hi guys, this is a simple code which is supposed to help the user to list the times table for n times. However, i am receiving undefined behaviour and I am quite stumped as to what is wrong with my implementation of my "for" loop.

I am receiving this as my output.

```
6356744 x 6356748 = 6356736
```

for n times in my consoles.

I want to ask

1. Is anything wrong with the logic of my code? (i assume i do have a problem with my code so please do enlighten me)
2. Would it be better(or even possible) to use pointers to point to the memory addresses of the mentioned variables when i have to change the value of the variables constantly? If yes, how do i go around doing it?

Thanks!

Comment: Don't use `&` in printf.

Comment: I realized it may be as a result of my improper usage of scanf that resulted in the undefined behaviour. Any ideas?

Comment: You don't need to dereference in your printf. You pass in the pointer to the scanf function so it can place the integer within a variable outside of its scope. You pass by value into printf. Also ans is defined before you get the values via scanf, you need to do the calculation after the scanf calls.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie ahh i see! however, my answer still gives an output showing that there still is undefined behaviour

Comment: @sacko87 So it would be okay for me to put the calculation within the loop? would it result in me creating an array inside the "ans" variable?

Comment: `ans = mult *i` gives undefined behaviour since, that that point, `mult` and `i` are both uninitialised (accessing the value of an uninitialised variable gives undefined behaviour).   That statement only works with current values of the variables - it doesn't set up some magic which causes `ans` to be updated whenever `i` or `mult` change.   Also, the `printf()` call gives undefined behaviour due to presence of ampersands (passing a pointer - or anything that is not an `int` - as argument corresponding to the `%d` format also gives undefined behaviour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In `printf` you must provide integers. You are now giving the addresses of integers. So change

```
printf("%d x %d = %d \n", &mult, &i , &ans);
```

to

```
printf("%d x %d = %d \n", mult, i, ans);
```

and to make the table, replace `ans` with just `mult*i`, so:

```
printf("%d x %d = %d \n", mult, i, mult*i);
```

---

You should also check the return value of scanf to check if it has succeeded reading your input:

```
do {
    printf("Please enter a multiple you want to explore.");
} while (scanf("%d", &mult)!=1);
do {
    printf("Please enter the number which you would want to multiply this number till.");
} while (scanf("%d", &n)!=1);
```

Comment: "to  have a leading space " is unnecessary. `scanf("%d"...` skips leadings white-spaces.

Comment: @chux, I read "_A white-space character causes scanf to read, but not store, all consecutive white-space characters in the input up to the next non–white-space character_". (But I am not a guru in scanf - should I adapt my answer?)

Comment: The issue of not what a white-space character does.  It is what `"%d"` does, which includes "Input white-space characters (as specified by the `isspace` function) are skipped, unless the specification includes a `[`, `c`, or `n` specifier"   C11 §7.21.6.2 7.  With that functionality, a leading `" "` is redundant. Adapt as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

The things you see are the values of the variables memory location.
Change your lines inside for loop as below

```
ans = mult * i;
printf("%d x %d = %d \n", mult, i, ans);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are some mistakes in your code .

1. you are using the & operator in print statement which is used to print the address of the variable.
2. Initiate the loop with the value '1' instead of '0' & execute the loop till 'i' less than equal to 'n'.
3. instead of using the ans variable outside the loop , use it inside the loop as it evaluate the multiplication result in each iteration of the loop.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main()
{
    int i;
    int mult;
    int n;
    int ans;

    printf("Please enter a multiple you want to explore.");
    scanf("%d", &mult);
    printf("Please enter the number which you would want to multiply this number till.");
    scanf("%d", &n);

    for(i = 1; i<=n; i++) {
        ans = mult*i ;
        printf("%d x %d = %d \n", mult, i , ans);
    }

    return 0;
}
```

[image]